# Finding the change ratio from given question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

First post here.

So, to further explain my question, I want to know what to look for when trying to determine what value changes with respect to the other value; basically which value is $x$, and which is $y$?

Here's a following table to help illustrate:

| Time | 06:00 | 10:00 | 14:00 | 18:00 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Temperature | +4°C | -2°C | +4°C | -2°C |

Question here is: Find the change ratio between 14:00 and 18:00. Is time here the $x$-value or is it the temperature? And how do we find out?

Comment: It would make more sense to model the temperature as a function of time; so the temperature is the $y$ value, the time is the $x$ value

Comment: You are right that there isn't a MATHEMATICAL reason why you should model temperature as a function of time rather than the other way around, it's just that physically it would not make much sense to do the other way around really

Comment: Please use the [Markdown syntax for tables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-markdown-to-create-tables), and [MathJax](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) for math.

Comment: Does temperature depend upon time, or does time depend upon temperature? It should be easy to convince yourself that it is the former.

Comment: @bounceback I was rather thinking mathematically; the table is just an example.

Comment: -2:4=-1/2, between 14:00 and 18:00 the temperature dropped 1 C per 2 hours

Comment: You can choose either one to be $x$ or $y$. Switching them will simply give an inverse ration like $3:2\longrightarrow 2:3$.

Comment: @poetasis That's what I discovered, later on. It seems I was a bit silly, but I hope I won't mistake with that again. Thanks for everyone's input! Very much appreciated